# The right way to early close request with large payload ( a image ) without error

Tags: rust, actix-web

a simplest http handler func like

```
pub async fn new(mut payload: web::Payload) -> Result<impl Responder> {
    return Ok("ok");
}
```

will raise error in the log:

```
[2022-06-03T01:39:58Z DEBUG actix_http::h1::dispatcher] cannot read request payload
[2022-06-03T01:39:58Z DEBUG actix_http::h1::dispatcher] handler dropped payload early; attempt to clean connection
[2022-06-03T01:39:58Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] handler did not read whole payload and dispatcher could not drain read buf; return 500 and close connection
[2022-06-03T01:39:58Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: Handler dropped payload before reading EOF
```

Seems that caused by the reason we haven't consume the payload.

Is there any way to fix this probrem?

What I really want to do is to protected a handler like this:

```
pub async fn new(user: User, mut payload: web::Payload) -> Result<impl Responder> {
    /*
      Do something with payload.
    */
}
```

where User implements the FromRequest trait, in its from_request function it will return an User or return the Unauthorized error.

So if there is an Unauthorized user calls the handler, it will return ErrorUnauthorized early.
But this will case the
`stream error: Handler dropped payload before reading EOF`.

Comment: Your payload might be larger than the default config. Check out https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.PayloadConfig.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to:

https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/2695

You likely need to drain the payload before returning your response/error. You can do so as:

```rust
payload.for_each(|_| ready(())).await;
```

or

```rust
while let Ok(Some(_)) = payload.try_next().await {}
```

I ran into a similar issue with processing multipart file uploads. Draining the payload as outlined above in option one worked in most cases, however, in some instances, like in the case the user hits the 'stop' or 'refresh' button on their browser, and the interruption occurs while looping on the stream, reading chunks of the payload would error 'Incomplete'. Attempting to turn the stream into a future and running `for_each()` on it would hang indefinitely. Option two worked consistently regardless.

Assuming your issue is interrelated, hopefully it should be resolved in v4.2, although you may still have to do some housekeeping with the payload when processing it like you are.

As far as the authorization comment, you can do this in a number of ways. One option is in middleware:

[Rust Actix - early return from middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929077/rust-actix-early-return-from-middleware/73186863#73186863)